# Bootstrap 3 rows are offset by 30px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning boostrap and am converting a small site (the hottowel for angulare template) from Bootstrap 2.x with container-fluid and row-fluid rows to use Bootstrap 3 with container and row (since they are fluid by default).

I keep running into this problem where all of the content in my rows is a few pixels too far to the left. (so the content in my main content area is clipped by the sidebar on the left).

After some digging in the debugger, I found that the rows are all inheriting a -30px margin from bootstrap.min.css.

My question is why, and what is the correct thing to do to make my rows appear in the correct position (they are in a container that is contained in a section that is my main content area)

Answer (score 0):

Lacking an example of your markup, it's worth noting that the [BS3 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) state that the only "allowed" children of a `row-` element is a `col-` element. If you use any other class or don't apply the `col-` class, your layout will be offset (which is likely what you're seeing).

You also need to make sure you've specified the `viewport` meta tag, or the media queries don't get picked up properly:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: I saw that in the docs.  I'm very new to bootstrap, so maybe I don't understand.  I don't have anything in a row that does not have a class="col-sm-x" class applied.  It looked like that was what the examples were doing.  So do I have to wrap everything in divs?  (like a label in col 1 must be in a div, and then the textbox in col2 must be in a different div?)

Comment: @JMarsch `xs`, `sm`, `md`, and `lg` all target different viewport widths, and use different "gutters". `sm` is for viewports less than `750px` wide: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options - if you're targeting desktop browsers, add (**not** replace) one of the `col-md-` or `col-lg-` columns. You don't have to have everything in a div, but the **immediate** children of an element with a `row` class must have a `col-` class.

Comment: @JMarsch The idea is that you could have something like `class="col-xm-6 col-md-4"` on an element, which would make it take up half the screen on a smaller device but only 1/3 of the screen on a larger device. You don't have to use the same column definition at each breakpoint.